# cd command does not work in my shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, directory, cd-command

I have a script `.sh` that creates a directory and moves to this directory some files.
I want to change the directory to this new one just created, but it doesn't work with the command

```
cd ./$dirname1${iloop}
```

where `$dirname1${iloop}` is the name of the new directory...how can I change directory?

`mkdir ./$dirname1${iloop}`

```
`cp $in1 ./$dirname1${iloop}`

`cp $plot  ./$dirname1${iloop}`

`cp $tmpl1 ./$dirname1${iloop}`

`cp $in2 ./$dirname1${iloop}`

`cp $tmpl2 ./$dirname1${iloop}`

`cp $data ./$dirname1${iloop}`

`cd ./$dirname1${iloop}`
```

Comment: Maybe you want to share the whole script with us...?

Comment: Your variables might not be getting set correctly. See if you can simply print the directory name. And read more here http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/ in particular the bit about `set -u`

Comment: I'm sure that the variables that are files are copied correctly in the directory because i have checked it. The problem is when I ask to change directory: the command cd is not executed and the shell remains in the starting directory.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you posted your script as it really is, this command:

```
`cd ./$dirname1${iloop}`
```

uses process substitution. The ticks

```
`
```

at the front and end are the old syntax for what in new typing is `$()`. While coping files has lasting consequences both within and without the substitution, if you `cd` in process substitution or a subshell, the directory change is only valid in that context. After you come back to the basic shell, you are back to where you were before.

Compare these two from the command line:

```
$(cd /bin) && pwd
```

And

```
cd /bin && pwd
```